# Is there a way to generate report on Modern Site pages' views?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage, analytics

As of now, when we open a modern page / hover on a page, we can see Views count and also Viewers. Also, when we go to the siteanalytics page, we can view Site level views / viewer reports in past 3 months

Our Communication team want analytics on the Site pages. They want monthly metrics about viewers and views. Do we have access to the data source? Is there a way for us to customize the reports?

I checked Search API, which provides views count, but its too hard to search for each page in the site and also I can't guarantee every page would be covered through it.

Answer (score 1):

The View count on the side menu of the page is based on the property `ViewsLifeTime`.

We do not have access to the data source from UI, but we can get this value of each page using PowerShell.

Here’s a sample script for your reference.

```
#Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer.      
#Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")      
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")      
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll")   

function Get-SPOListView {  
    param(  
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)][string]$Username,  
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]$AdminPassword,  
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 3)][string]$Url,  
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 4)][string]$ListTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 5)][string]$TenantUrl) 

    #Get the SharePoint List / Library.  
    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)  
    $ll = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)  
    $ctx.load($ll)  
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

    #Get all items from the List / Library.  
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()  
    $items = $ll.GetItems($qry)  
    $ctx.Load($items)  
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

    #CSV file location, to store the result  
    $exportlocation = $filepath
    Write-Output "Title `t Path `t ViewsLifeTime `t ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers" | Out-file $filepath

    foreach($listItem in $items) {  
        Write-Host "ID - ", $listItem["ID"]  
        "Title - "
        $listItem["Title"]  
        "EncodedAbsUrl - "
        $listItem["FileRef"]  
        $fileurl = $TenantUrl + $listItem["FileRef"]  

        #Using Search API - Create the instance of KeywordQuery and set the properties.  
        $keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($ctx)  

        #Sample Query - To get the result of last year.  
        $queryText = "Path:" + $fileurl  
        $keywordQuery.QueryText = $queryText  
        $keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = $false  
        $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ViewsLifeTime")  
        $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers")  
        $keywordQuery.SortList.Add("ViewsLifeTime", "Asc")  

        #Search API - Create the instance of SearchExecutor and get the result.  
        $searchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor($ctx)  
        $results = $searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

        #Result Count  
        Write-Host $results.Value[0].ResultRows.Count   
        foreach($result in $results.Value[0].ResultRows) {  
            $outputline = "$($result["Title"]) `t $($result["Path"]) `t $($result["ViewsLifeTime"]) `t $($result["ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers"])"
            Add-Content $exportlocation $outputline  
        }
    }  
}  

#Insert the credentials along with Admin & Tenant URLs and Call above Function.     
$Username = "<Admin>"      
$pass = "<Password>"
$Password = convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force
#URL of the site collection      
$rootUrl = "<SiteURL>"      
$ListTitle = "Site Pages"      
$TenantUrl = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com"
$filepath = "C:\Temp\Pages_ViewsCount.csv" 

Get-SPOListView -Username $Username -AdminPassword $Password -Url $rootUrl -ListTitle $ListTitle -TenantUrl $TenantUrl
```

If you want monthly metrics on this report, I suggest you use audit log reports instead.

Reference (Careful with typos in the original sample):

[Office 365/SharePoint Online - PowerShell Script to Get and Export Site Pages ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers & ViewsLifeTime Details.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/office-365sharepoint-online-powershell-script-to-get-export-site-pages-viewslifetimeuniqueusers-viewslifetime-details)

[How to Generate a Page View Report in SharePoint Online.](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2014/09/21/page-views-in-0365-sharepoint-online)